# Get first row of each of several conditions

Tags: postgresql

I have the following table on a PostgreSQL database with ids, dates and boolean values as `1` or `null`:

```
id  updated_at  cc_enabled  tp_enabled
1   2021-01-07  1           
1   2021-01-08              1           
1   2021-01-09  1           1
2   2021-01-07  1           1
2   2021-01-09              1
3   2021-01-07  1           1
3   2021-01-09  1           1
3   2021-01-10  1
3   2021-01-11              1
3   2021-01-12  1           1
```

I would like to get only the first time that each "boolean" row (`cc_enabled` and `tp_enabled`) is `1` (true)
The idea is to only have a maximum of one "true" per condition per ID.

So this should be the result:

```
id  updated_at  cc_enabled  tp_enabled
1   2021-01-07  1                      -- first time for cc_enabled = 1 for id 1
1   2021-01-08              1          -- first time for tp_enabled = 1 for id 2
2   2021-01-07  1           1
3   2021-01-07  1           1          -- first time for both conditions = 1 for id 3
```

At the end, I would like to summarize by day and by id and not get more than `number_of_conditions*number_of_ids`.

I can't wrap my head around this, I tried to adapt windows fuctions or subqueries but none worked so far without giving me duplicated rows or just not working.

Comment: In your expected result, why does the first row for id=2 not have `tp_enabled`? And if it should have it set to `1`, those the second row for id=2 still appear then?

Comment: You say <The idea is to only have a maximum of one "true" per condition per ID>. This is not the case for the last row of your expected result. Why is it in the result set?

Comment: I edited my post with more details to clarify. Each condition is evaluated separately for each id. @Marth

Comment: @MonoColorado: There's still a `3; 2021-01-07` that should take the place of the `3; 2021-01-09` it the output I think. The `2; 2021-01-07` also has both values to `true`, not just `cc_enabled` like in your result set.

Comment: @MichalT I mean that each condition should be true once per id. Both conditions could be "true" the same day. Days might repeat. "true" conditions per id shouldn't.

Comment: @Marth sorry, you are right, I corrected the examples